# Failed to change embebed-tomcat default port using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to run two spring boot on my eclipse.
So I need to set up one port on one of spring boot not to default.
I added server.port:8888 on application.properties file
then when I run spring boot, it still run on 8080 port

Does anyone have the same situation? and how do you solve that?

thank you

Comment: could you show your application.properties and place (path) of that in project?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem basing on provider answers?

Answer (score 0):

For the case, you have created `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` Bean programatically then you need to set port from the Bean.

Set port from `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` as from `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
  int port = 8888;
  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("", port);
}
```